# Run check before all $state.go() events in one controller ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular-ui-router and have a controller with multiple `$state.go()` events, various buttons will navigate you to other views.

Is there a way to run a function to check conditions before any `$state.go()` (in this controller) event is executed without adding the check manually before each `$state.go()` function?

Basically I want to check if you are in an edit mode, prompt the user, and then execute accordingly.

I'm wondering if there is a angular-ui-router method that can help me with this.  I know this can be accomplished with without using angular-ui-router.

Comment: Perhaps using the `$stateChangeStart` event?

Comment: You can use the `$scope.$on()` to listen to `$stateChangeStart` event, see the bottom http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state

Answer (score 1):

Hi tester: there is if you inject $state into your controller, which it sounds like you have done... you can use `$state.current.name`. This will give you the current name of the state you are in like:

`.state('dashboard.welcome', {
        url: '/welcome',
        data: {
            title: 'Welcome to my company',
        },
        permissions: {
           has: ['authenticated', 'completed'],
        },
    });`

If you do this inside the controller: you will get `console.log($state.current.name)`=> 'dashboard.welcome'.
Which is good for your edit scenario...
`if($state.current.name) == 'dashboard.edit'){
$state.go(destination);
}
else if...`

Another thing you may have noticed from my example is permissions: it sounds like you could potentially benefit from this [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-permission) The npm is called angular-permission (which will inevitably be a broken link one day). Which is pretty cool.

To use it you basically can say:does the user have this criteria? if yes they can access this page. Otherwise... redirectTo: 'blahblah'.

But in my page where I am navigating a lot based on certain criteria I have that be in the $parent.controller so as you know a child state with the ui-router will have access to its' parent's controller and its functions so I have a function like:

```
$scope.switchToState = function(){
        if($state.current.name === ''){
            var destination = 'formy.firstPage';
            var routeParams = {};
            if(account.check('mycriteria')){
                destination = 'form.secondPageInstead';
            }
            else if(angular.isString(LocalStorage.secondCriteria)){
                destination = 'form.otherPage';
                routeParams = {id: LocalStorage.secondCriteria};
            }
           ...
            $timeout( //often needed is the $timeout to wait for DOM to 
                function(){
                    if(routeParams.slug){
                        $state.go(destination, routeParams);
                    }
                    else{
                        $state.go(destination);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
```

Now in every child controller rather than saying at the end of each function $state.go('somewhere') I do $scope.switchToState() and it routes everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was a combination of what @elclanrs and @Zargold suggested.

I set a global `$scope` variable to check if I was in editing mode.  Then on `$scope.$on($stateChangeStart ...` checked the name of the current `$state` and proceeded accordingly.

Note I'm using `$scope` insead of `$rootScope` for the `$stateChangeStart` so it only checks for state changes in this controller's scope.

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options){
        if($state.current.name === 'dashboard.welcome' && $scope.isInEditMode) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $modal.open({
                animation: false,
                templateUrl: 'modal.html',
                controller: 'ModalCtrl',
                size: 'sm',
                resolve: {
                    onSuccess: function() {
                        return function(){
                           //continues the state change
                            $scope.isInEditMode = false;
                            $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```